# Calculus and derivatives problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I approach and solve a question like this? I have come to a solution of:
[image] 
However I do not know if this is correct.

**Here is the problem:**

Alcohol enters the blood stream at a constant rate of k grams per liter per hour during a drinking session. The liver gradually converts the alcohol to other non-toxic byproducts. The rate of conversion is proportional to the current blood alcohol concentration of c(t) grams per liter, so that the differential equation satisﬁed by the blood alcohol level is

[image]

where a is a unitless positive constant. Suppose initially there is no alcohol in the blood. Find the blood alcohol concentration as a function of time from t=0, when the drinking started. You must show and explain how you get the solution - quoting a formula from the notes or from lecture is insufficient.

Comment: Are you sure that's right? The solution you gave is the same as the problem.

Comment: Sorry I fixed it now! The original equation given is the differential.

Comment: Check your work by differentiating $c(t)$ and sticking it into the equation. If the answer is right, the equality will hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are given:

$$\tag 1 \dfrac{dc}{dt} = k-sc$$

This equation is separable, which leads to solving:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{k-sc}~dc = \int dt$$

This gives us the solution:

$$c(t) = \dfrac{1}{s}(k - e^{s(t + q)})$$

where $q$ is a constant.

At time $t=0$, we can assume there is no alcohol (unless you have some real issues) in the system, that is $c(0) = 0$. We have:

$$c(0) = \dfrac{1}{s}(k - e^{s(0 + q)}) = 0 \rightarrow \dfrac{1}{s}(k - e^{sq}) = 0 \rightarrow k - e^{sq} = 0 \rightarrow k = e^{sq} $$

Substituting this into the DEQ yields:

$$\tag 2 \large c(t) = \dfrac{k}{s}(1 - e^{-st})$$

To verify that this result is correct, we check two things:

- $c(0) = 0$
- That it solves the original DEQ, so the derivative of $(2)$:

$$\large \dfrac{dc}{dt} = ke^{-st}$$

The RHS of $(1)$ yields:

$$\large \dfrac{dc}{dt} = k - sc = k - s\left(\dfrac{k}{s}(1 - e^{-st})\right) = ke^{-st}$$

Indeed, everything checks out.

Comment: Instead of s it is meant to be the constant a. So should I just change s into a. Therefore, it would be dc/dt= k-ac and so on..?

Comment: Also, how can c(0)=0 when there is a constant of q next to t..? What if q is a positive number, then c(0) would not equal to 0.

Comment: At $t=0$, we get $e^{sq} = k$. You can call the variables anything you want, so if you want to change $s$ to $a$, go for it.

Comment: How can I solve this using the substitution method to get to the solution, not by integrating.

Comment: You can use Integrating Factor, Laplace Transforms or Exact Equations. Hopefully, you know how to do one of those, but now know the answer as all methods give identical results. Regards

Comment: can you show me how you got form step two to the solution with the constant q, please.

Comment: I added it to the answer.

Comment: How'd this go without $\uparrow$s? I'll fix that!

Comment: I see! Some OPs give us a workout!